# Correctly use deff() to define a function for use in ode solver

Tags: scilab

I have a differential equation

> y'=-0.1y + g(t), y(0)=1, 0<=t<=600,  g(t)=0 except between 488.3 &
>   488.9 where its value is 2.

which is to be simulated using scilab's ode() function assuming default options of %ODEOPTIONS.

The first step is to use

> deff()

to define our differential equation.  Then I will use

> ydiff=ode(y0,x0,x,f);

For a simple Differential equation such as:

> y′=x+1/y,   y(0)=0.1

I would express it as:

> deff('yprim=f(x,y)','yprim=(x+1)/y');

But in more complex case such as in my case shown above, where we have two functions f and g, I am unable to understand usage of deff.

Comment: Why not use a normal function block?

Comment: Just don't use `deff`. Write `function yprim = f(x, y) ... computation ... endfunction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `deff()` is

```
deff('[s1, s2, ...] = newfunction(e1, e2, ...)',text)
```

and `text` is a column-matrix of strings, and each of its lines would be lines in a functions block:

```
function y=foo(x)
    (Line 1)
    (Line 2)
    (Line 3)
endfunction
```

is equivalent to

```
deff("y=foo(x)"; ["(Line 1)";"(Line 2)";"(Line 3)"]);
```

So, in your problem, you could do:

```
deff("y = g(t)", ["if (t > 488.2 & t < 488.9) then"; "y = 2"; "else"; "y = 0"; "end"]);
deff("yprime = fode(t,y)", ["yprime = -0.1*y + g(t)"]);
```

Then you can use `ode()` as you normally would.